# What does Pickpocketing : Perfect Touch do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In particular, what types of items can I now steal that I couldn't before?  I've not noticed any difference in getting the perk.

Also, once I got the perk that lets you steal weapons, I noticed that the weapons appear sporadically in the list.  Maybe there is a trick to it I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The perk allows you to can pickpocket equipped items, like armor.

You can use it along with Misdirection to strip/gain a tactical advantage against a NPC (like Astrid) before you engage in combat with them. The can be useful with followers as well. Sometimes followers will refuse to equip the items you give them. You can use these two perks to pickpocket the items you wish to replace with the improved items. They also helps with NPCs who will not trade their equipped items with you.

Comment: I understand that's what it says, I'm looking for examples that people have experienced themselves (maybe I should have been more specific).

Comment: You can use it along with Misdirection to strip/gain a tactical advantage against a NPC (like Astrid) before you engage in combat with them. The can be useful with followers as well. Sometimes followers will refuse to equip the items you give them. You can use these two perks to pickpocket the items you wish to replace with the improved items. They also helps with NPCs who will not trade their equipped items with you.

Comment: I'm choosing your answer based on your very helpful comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can now pickpocket all equipped items from a character.

Keep in mind that you need to remain hidden from that character (other people noticing you is fine), and also, some characters with unique/special armor (like for instance, Ulfric) can't have their equipment stolen.

To test to make sure it's working, find a regular guard in any town, and while remaining hidden from them, try to pick their pocket. You should find lots of armor with little triangles to the left (to show they're equipped).

Comment: Yeah I haven't seen this.  You've seen this yourself?

Comment: @Killith — Yes. I've a habit of leaving mouthy guards naked and unarmed. ;-)

Comment: It would be great to pickpocket the scales off a dragon and find that it leaves him in a pair of boxer shorts with little red hearts on them. Hmmm....*fires up the Creation Kit*

Answer (score -1):

This is for when Sylgja won't wear anything other than miner's clothes. Then you can pickpocket her clothes and give her something sexier, like... gavern clothes for example.

Comment: That isn't enough explaining so -1.

Comment: Besides Sygia? Don't get this.